# Custom trackpad pan/zoom/rotate behavior add-on

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to write an addon to customize the trackpad panning, zoomimg, and rotating gestures, but can't find a way to read the actual trackpad parameters for position and so on. The properties in the event structure (mouse_prev_x/y, mouse_x/y, mouse_region_x/y) shows the current pointer position which happens to be standing still on the screen.

This is the addon that I'm talking about:

[space_view3d_pan_naturally.py](https://gist.github.com/rraallvv/5989609)

There are no examples on the web for handling the `TRACKPADPAN` event.

The class `bpy.types.Event` is the one that is supposed to have the relevant parameters to retrieve from the `TRACKPADPAN` event, that is what I'm guessing from the [documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.types.Event.html?highlight=event#bpy.types.Event.value).

This snippet of code in particular, from my add-on, printf to the info view that the trackpad event has nothing to do with the mouse coordinates that are available in `bpy.types.Event`

```
#....
def modal(self, context, event):
    #....
    if event.type == 'TRACKPADPAN':     
        self.report({'INFO'}, str(event.mouse_x))
#...
```

Comment: Could be a bug or missing feature, you should contact a dev in IRC.

Comment: @rraallvv was this ever resolved?

Comment: There is a patch for this on the developers page if you want to build your own blender from it ir take over the patch so it can go into official blender https://developer.blender.org/T30746

Comment: Have you tried reading through the C code to see how those events are generated?

Comment: @dr.Sybren If I remember correctly I needed to patch the sources in order to get the plugin to work correctly, but that kind of defeats the propose of scripting a plugin in the first place. I haven't tried with the latest release though.

Comment: Well, if you add something nice, you can always send in a patch and get it into Blender itself.

Comment: @dr.Sybren I'm mostly using maya for 3d modeling these days , but if I get the chance I'll give it a try with the latest release.

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually need, but try this https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/840439/navigating_with_a_trackpad/

Comment: pan - shift + click scroll button zoom in/out - Move scroll wheel up or down Rotate - click mouse button and move around.

Comment: trackpadpan, i can't find docs on an underlying library. my reasoning currently thinks this would be effectively trackpad "scroll" events, or atleast, by the time we're in desktop-land, a trackpad pan-up pan-down is often considered a mosuewheel up/down event.

so i wonder if part of the disconnect is coming from the hardware/driver/desktop before blender handles the event data at all. for comparison, SDL doesn't have a primitive for trackpad pan, [only down up and motion](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_TouchFingerEvent) from which we could build our own pan event accumulator glue DIY

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu *Edit > Preferences > Input* and tick the *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* checkbox.